# Get object in i18n form

Tags: forms, symfony1, internationalization, doctrine

Inside embedded i18n form i need to get object.
In this example i got `ArtistImageTranslation` object, but i need `ArtistImage`.

Can somebody help me, how to get this?

```
class ArtistImageTranslationForm extends BaseArtistImageTranslationForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->getObject();
    ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
$artistimage = $this->getObject()->getArtistImage();
```

Comment: I tried and got `Unknown method ArtistImageTranslation::getArtistImage`

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$artistimage = $this->getObject()->artistImage;
```

or

```
$artistimage = $this->getObject()->artist_image;
```

Comment: `$this->getObject()->artistImage` gives `Unknown record property / related component "artistImage" on "ArtistImageTranslation"` and `$this->getObject()->artist_image` gives `Unknown record property / related component "artist_image" on "ArtistImageTranslation"`

Answer (score 0):

I spent half of day today on the same problem and looks like I finally found something ;)

First, if you need to access the fields which are in the "Translation" part of the table you can access them directly from the Object contained in the form. Just access the properties without using the getter (I know it's not the nice way but it works). So you can use something like:

```
$this->getObject()->id;
$this->getObject()->translated_name;
```

etc.

If you really need the original object you can access it like this:

```
$this->getObject()->getTable()->getRelation('ArtistImage')
     ->fetchRelatedFor($this->getObject());
```

Hope this helps.